# Huxtable in R give wrong formatting when using by_cases()

Tags: r

When I run this

```
library(tidyverse)

df = data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              Type = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                 A = c(51, 5, 10, 155.5),
                 P1 = c(40.1, 50.5, 127.8, 216),
                 C = c(40, 45, 50, 255)
     )

library(huxtable)
ht = as_hux(df)
ht %>% map_text_color( row = 2:nrow(df), col = 2:3,
                    by_cases(. < 50 ~ "red")) %>%
  set_all_borders()
ht
```

I get table:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YplP2.jpg)

The problem is that 127.8 is bigger than 50 so it shouldn't be red. How to make it to be as I want?

Comment: Underlying issue is that adding cases has turned your numbers to `character()`. A workaround is to use `by_cases(as.numeric(.) < 50 ~ "red")`.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying issue is that adding cases has turned your numbers to `character()`. A workaround is to use `by_cases(as.numeric(.) < 50 ~ "red")`. Alternatively, write:

```r
ht = as_hux(df, add_colnames = FALSE)
ht %>% map_text_color(col = 2:3,
                    by_cases(. < 50 ~ "red")) %>%
  add_colnames() %>%
  set_all_borders() %>%
```

which keeps the data as numeric until after you've done the colour mapping.